# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I cannot compile the code, below, because i have 17 errors regarding  "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context".
It is always pointing at the `this` keyword.

```
package MyLib;
import java.util.*;

class Book {

static int pages;
static String Title;
static String Author;
static int status;
static String BorrowedBy;
static Date ReturnDate;
static Date DueDate;

public static final int
    BORROWED = 0;

public static final int
    AVAILABLE = 1;

public static final int
    RESERVED = 2;

    //constructor
public Book ( String Title, String Author, int pp) {
    this.Title = Title;
    this.Author = Author;
    this.pages = pp;
    this.status = this.AVAILABLE;
}

public static void borrow(String Borrower/*, Date Due*/){
    if (this.status=this.AVAILABLE){
        this.BorrowedBy=Borrower;
        this.DueDate=Due;
    
    }
    else {
    
        if(this.status == this.RESERVED && this.ReservedBy == Borrower){
            this.BorrowedBy= Borrower;
            this.DueDate=Due;
            this.ReservedBy="";
            this.status=this.BORROWED;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access non-static i.e. instance members from static init blocks or methods.

- static is related to class and instance variables are related to instances of the class.
- The reference of `this` means you are referring to the current object of class.
- A static block is related to class so it does not have the information about the objects. So it cannot identify `this`.

In your example. you shoud make the method `borrow` non-static. It means they will relate to object of class and you can use `this`.

Answer (score 2):

In one sentence,

> you cannot use **["this keyword"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)** inside a static context, such as static methods/static initializers.

Answer (score 1):

static variables are class wide. *this* is object wide. (in other words is reliant on an instance of the object) You have to instantiate an object to get access to *this*

The opposite is not true. You can access static variables from object instances